# gt_summary / tbl_summary > Error in mutate_cols(): ! Problem with mutate() column df_stats. i df_stats = pmap(...)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

For a few days, all my tables have stopped loading too. I think that the problem comes from gtsummary package.

I have the same error message when I test the example from R:

```
tbl_summary_ex2 <- trial %>% 
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = trt, 
              label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"), 
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"), 
              digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1)))
```

There was an error calculating the summary statistics for "age". Is this variable's class supported by mean and sd?

> Error in mutate_cols(): ! Problem with mutate() column df_stats. i df_stats = pmap(...). x message must be a character vector, not a <rlang_error/error/condition> object. Caused by error in abort(): ! message must be a character vector, not a <rlang_error/error/condition> object. Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.

And when I drop `({sd})` it works.

I've checked the dependencies of packages and the version, it seems ok. I also tried to restart and reload `gtsummary`/`tidyverse`, the error message persists.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you in advance, Estelle

Comment: Here on R4.0.3 and gtsummary_1.5.2 & tidyverse_1.3.1 there are no problems. Have you run rlang::last_error()?

Comment: The code also works on my machine. I suggest you close all your R sessions, open a single session with nothing loaded, reinstall gtsummary, and try your code again.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I had R 3.6.2 version and after updated it works well. Thanks for your help.  Estelle

Comment: I received this error when one of the columns passed was a named number. Conversion to numeric fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and noticed that it occurs after loading the dplyr library - possibly the culprit in your case as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).